# How to position form above header image using css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to position a form above header image, i made some css styling but it gets above the footer too. How can I make the footer remain at the bottom of this form not below it and to be responsive too?

My sample code on codepen : https://codepen.io/fatehalrabeai/pen/KKwreWd

```
body{
  position:relative;
}
.container{
  background-color: blue;
  paddding:30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 4px #c3b4b4;
  height:400px;
  position:absolute;
  top:400px;
  left:50px
}

footer{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative margin-top to do this, also you can use margin-bottom to move the footer down. I have edited your codepen:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 4px #c3b4b4;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <header>
    <img style="width:100%; height: 600px;  " src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="">
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <h1>Footer </h1>
  </footer>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) you can get more involve on this topic

Comment: This is what I actually attempt to do : https://ibb.co/vZnZpg2

Answer (score 3):

Hope this one will help you....

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>

.form-wrapper{
  padding:30px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 4px #c3b4b4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #0000007d;

}

footer{
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}
.bg_banner{
    background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random);
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;

}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>



    
  <section class="bg_banner">
    
    <div class ="container ">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <div class ="row"> 
          <div class ="col-lg-12">
                <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="text-white">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="text-white">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
              <label class="form-check-label text-white" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
                    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </section>

    <footer>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <p class="text-center mb-0 text-white">made with &hearts; by jishnu</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace my code with yours. 
HTML

```
 <header>
      <img  style="width:100%; height: 600px;  " src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="">
      <div class ="container-2">
      <div class ="row"> 
        <div class ="col-lg-12">
      <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
header{
  position:relative;
}
.container-2{
  background-color: blue;
  paddding:30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 4px #c3b4b4;
  height:400px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  width:500px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: I need it to be positioned in middle of the image using position :absolute. my only problem is with the footer

Comment: @Developer updated the answer please check and if this helps you so please mark my answer as correct. Thanks